# Avoid out of memory error for multiprocessing Pool

Tags: python, multithreading, memory, multiprocessing

How do I avoid "out of memory" exception when a lot of sub processes are launched using multiprocessing.Pool?

First of all, my program loads 5GB file to a object. Next, parallel processing runs, where each process *read* that 5GB object.

Because my machine has more than 30 cores, I want to use full of my cores. However, when launching 30 sub processes, `out of memory` exception occurs.

Probably, each process has the copy of the large instance (5GB). The total memory is 5GB * 30 core = 150GB. That's why out of memory error occurs.

I believe there is a workaround to avoid this memory error because each process just read that object. If each process share memory of the huge object, only 5GB memory is enough for my multi processing.

Please let me know a workaround of this memory error.

```
import cPickle
from multiprocessing import Pool
from multiprocessing import Process
import multiprocessing
from functools import partial

with open("huge_data_5GB.pickle", "rb") as f
    huge_instance = cPickle(f)

def run_process(i, huge_instance):
    return huge_instance.get_element(i)

partial_process = partial(run_process, huge_instance=huge_instance)

p = Pool(30) # my machine has more than 30 cores
result = p.map(partial_process, range(10000))
```

Comment: look at the `mmap` module.

Comment: you could switch from `multiprocessing` to `multithread`: memory would be shared. Or is that a no-go for you?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre they would also share a single core... ;-)  -- or at least a single GIL

Comment: @thebjorn Thank you very much. Google told me that mmap is a module realizing "memory mapped file" in python. But, I could not how to use mmap for my purpose. Could you please give a sample code?

Comment: looking at your code closer, this `huge_instance = cPickle(f)` will depickle the entire file and create objects. There is no sensible way to share something like that.  Perhaps you'll need to re-evalutate using pickle as a storage format.. or buy more memory (150GB isn't that much for a 30 core machine...)

Comment: @thebjorn right! 30 cores? is that xmas yet :) I know that by default memory is copied, but isn't it possible to share python objects through multiprocesses? after all it's the same memory there.

Comment: How much RAM for this 30 core beast? For example, let's say, you launch 29 subprocesses, keep 1 for the main python process. Each process consumes 5 GB RAM since you have 5GB zip files and they are being loaded in memory so 29 x 5 = 145 GB RAM for loading the data and extracting it. we are looking at 150GB of RAM.